# Understanding onetomany and manytoone JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I can't understand how works oneToMany and manyToOne in JPA. For a sample I have to entity.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Skills> skillList
}
```

and another one

```
@Entity
public class SkillList {
    private String skillName;
    private byte skillLevel;
}
```

How to correct link this entities? Also If anyone can explain it in an accessible way.

Comment: OneToMany: A has 0-N Bs (and a B belongs to a single A). Example: an order has several order lines (and an order line belongs to a single order). ManyToOne: B belongs to a single A (and A can have several Bs). Example: an order line belongs to a single order (and the order can have several lines). Your association is none of the above. A customer has several skills, but a skill doesn't belong to a single customer: several customers can have the same skill. So it's a ManyToMany.

Comment: For the technical stuff (annotations, etc.), why don't you read the documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In database one to many relationship is achieved by foreign key.
In order to link two entities in Java according to JPA specification you should use `@ManyToOne` annotation or both `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` if you need bidirectional association.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Skill> skills;
}

@Entity
public class Skill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String skillName;
    private byte skillLevel;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
}
```

It will generate two tables in the database. Table `SKILL` has column `CUSTOMER_ID` which relates to `CUSTOMER` table.

Comment: Actually, if schema generation is enabled, it will generate three tables (one for Customer, one for Skill, and one join table).

Comment: @SerSergious if you want help, you need to be much more precise than that. Edit your question, tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.